# the lifetime 'a as defined on the body does not necessarily outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to create a function (`f1`) that adds an element to an array.

Here is my Rust code:

```
use std::mem;

struct T1<'a> {
    value: &'a str,
}

fn main() {   
    let mut data: [T1; 1] = unsafe { mem::uninitialized() };
    f1("Hello", &mut data[..]);
}

fn f1<'b, 'a: 'b>(s: &'a str, data: &'b mut[T1]) {   
    data[0] = T1::<'a> { value: s };
}
```

I get this error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:13:15
   |
13 |     data[0] = T1::<'a> { value: s };
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `T1<'_>`
   = note:    found type `T1<'a>`
note: the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 12:49...
  --> <anon>:12:50
   |
12 |   fn f1<'b, 'a: 'b>(s: &'a str, data: &'b mut[T1]) {   
   |  __________________________________________________^ starting here...
13 | |     data[0] = T1::<'a> { value: s };
14 | | }
   | |_^ ...ending here
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 12:49
  --> <anon>:12:50
   |
12 |   fn f1<'b, 'a: 'b>(s: &'a str, data: &'b mut[T1]) {   
   |  __________________________________________________^ starting here...
13 | |     data[0] = T1::<'a> { value: s };
14 | | }
   | |_^ ...ending here
help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn f1<'b, 'a:'b>(s: &'a str, data: &'b mut [T1<'a>])
  --> <anon>:12:1
   |
12 |   fn f1<'b, 'a: 'b>(s: &'a str, data: &'b mut[T1]) {   
   |  _^ starting here...
13 | |     data[0] = T1::<'a> { value: s };
14 | | }
   | |_^ ...ending here
```

Is there a way to write `f1` that does what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You code is not very idiomatic and uses `unsafe` for a very simple operation already. Do you know about [`Vec<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html)? It's a dynamically allocated array with convenience methods like `push()`. If you can't or don't want to use the heap, you can use the crate `arrayvec` which wraps an stack allocated array and provides many useful methods as well. You certainly don't want to do that yourself like that...

Comment: I didn't know about arrayvec. Certainly it can improve my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify lifetime to the slice parameter:

```
fn f1<'b, 'a: 'b>(s: &'a str, data: &'b mut [T1<'a>]) {
    data[0] = T1::<'a> { value: s };
}
```

Comment: Could you explain *why* the lifetime parameter needs to be specified?

Comment: As this is already accepted: the lifetime `'b` can be removed from the signature and the `::<'a>` can be removed from the body. The compiler is able to infer those two things.